# `migrate` fails to detect new model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I've just created a new model in `project/posts/models.py` but `manage.py migrate` completes without creating the new model. Similarly `manage.py makemigrations` detects no changes either and returns `No changes detected`. Does anyone know why the new model is not detected?

Answer (score 0):

Is your app `posts` listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`in your `settings.py` file? That might be the issue.

Also you can try with:

```
manage.py makemigrations posts
```

Comment: It's not, but I have `project.posts.apps.AppConfig` in there, which contains a class extending `AppConfig`. Is that adequate?